# Complex sequence $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ with $p$ limit points

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

$f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous and a sequence $u$ is defined by :

$u_0\in \mathbb C$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$

What can be said about this sequence if it has exactly $p$ limit points ?

It is known that if this sequence has exactly one limit point, then it converges ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829913/if-the-complex-sequence-u-n1-fu-n-has-only-one-limit-point-then-it-conve))

Comment: Have you thought about just the case of two limit points?

Comment: Well, I don't know what I should think about it...

Comment: In fact, neither do I. The only thing I can think of is an example : take $f(x) = -x$ starting at $u_0 = 1$ to see that $f(1) = -1$, then $f(-1) =1$ and so on , so the sequence is just $1,-1,1,-1,...$ , and you can see there are two limit points, with the catch being that $1 = f(-1)$. A possibly interesting statement could be that if $a$ and $b$ are the limit points then there is some relation between $a$ and $b$ (like here we had $a = f(b)$ and $b = f(a)$). That is a useful statement, now that I think of it!

Comment: I just deleted all of my previous comments.  It just hit me that I have not come to terms with the fact that $f$ is required to be continuous.  Therefore, I think that my previous comments might well have been in error.